# Can two different View be returned onCreateView method?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have ListView within listView i have text,text,linearLayout.LinearLayout has another view to be inflated within the ListView.I have one main **View=view** which is returned showing the listView, but i am struggling to return the value of view1 on the LinearLayout.

**Fee class**

```
public class Fee extends Fragment /*implements View.OnClickListener   */ {

    LinearLayout receipt1, receipt2, receipt3, receipt4;
    LinearLayout receipt1detail, receipt2detail, receipt3detail, receipt4detail;
    LinearLayout DescriptionAmount;


    TextView statustextView;
    ListView listViewfees, listviewfeedetail;
    List<StudentFeeInformation> yourData = new ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation>();

    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Api/financeApi/getAllFees";
    String Amount;
    String Descriptionlist, status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate;
    String master_id;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    View view1;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_listview, container, false);

        view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_description_data, container, false);
      **how can view1 be returned**

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        receipt1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_receipt1_fee);

        //  receipt4 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_receipt4_fee);

        //  receipt1detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt1_fee);
        //  receipt2detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt2_fee);
        //  receipt3detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt3_fee);
        //  receipt4detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt4_fee);

        //   receipt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt2.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt3.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt4.setOnClickListener(this);


        //   receipt1detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //   receipt2detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   receipt3detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   receipt4detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view1.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_linearlayout1);


        statustextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_status);
        SessionManagement sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        master_id = sessionManagement.getMasterId();
        listViewfees = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_student_fees);
        // listviewfeedetail = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtest);

        //    DescriptionAmount = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_linearlayout1);
        // DescriptionAmount.addView(view);

        getUsersListData();


        return view;
    }


    private void getUsersListData() {


        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?id=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<FeeDescriptionStudent> student_list_description = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                status = jsonObject.getString("Status");
                                DateofReceiptIssued = jsonObject.getString("DateOfReciept").substring(0, 10);
                                ReceiptNumber = jsonObject.getString("RecieptNo");
                                FeeReceivedDate = jsonObject.getString("recivedDate").substring(0, 10);


                                String Description = jsonObject.getString("Description");
                                JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(Description);


                                for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {


                                    JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                    Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
                                    Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");

                                    TextView txtQuestion = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
                                    TextView tx = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);


                                    txtQuestion.setText(Descriptionlist);
                                    tx.setText(Amount);

                                    linearLayout.addView(view1);

                                    //  Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
                                    //  Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");


                                }

                                // student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate, Descriptionlist, Amount));
                                student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));

                            }

                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_list.size());
                            CustomFeeListStudentAdapter customFeeListStudentAdapter = new CustomFeeListStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list);
                            listViewfees.setAdapter(customFeeListStudentAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

**fragment_fee**

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/receipt1_fee"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#A4ACB0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Description"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Amount (Nrs) "
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">


                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_linearlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_description"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Sports"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_amount"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="1000"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />    -->


                </LinearLayout>
```

linearlayout to be inflated
**student_fees_description_data**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Sports"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="1000"
        android:textSize="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> How can two view be returned and one inflated to the linearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution :

1.Remove:

```
view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_description_data, container, false);
```

2. Inflate view1 layout using below code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_description_data, container, false);
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: please post code on which line your getting problem?

Comment: issue on

                                    TextView txtQuestion = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
                                    TextView tx = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);


                                    System.out.println(txtQuestion);
                                    System.out.println(tx);

Comment: post code how you written how you inflating the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138623/discussion-between-ghimire-and-rajasekhar).